# How to make the emojis display well in windows android studio code editor view?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, emoji, jetbrains-ide

How to use emoji in the Android source code in Android studio or IntelliJ in Windows OS? I want to use emojis in the logcat print messages by choosing emojis from the context-sensitive popup. I could not find the right plugin.
I need the plugin that is used in the picture below. But don't know how to achieve the same. When I googled I get references to emoji-compat for showing emoji in the android application's soft keyboard dialog. But I want to use emoji in the source code in the comments and logcat only.
[image]

**Update:** I thought it is an android studio feature. But it is available as soft touch keyboard in windows 10. "WIN + ;" is the shortcut for launching the same.
[image]

Now, my next question is how to make the emojis display colorful in windows android studio's code editor and logcat like the way it appears in the Mac.
In Mac it appears like this:
[image] 
In windows it appears like this in the editor after adding the emoji:
[image]

Comment: please make your question more clear and better add some example what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3):

1. On mac position the cursor in any text field you'd like to insert an
   emoji, like posting a tweet for example.

   2. Use the keyboard shortcut Command - Control - Space bar to access
      emoji.
   3. Double-click the emoji you'd like to use and it'll be inserted where
      you left your cursor.

Answer (score 3):

In your screenshots, the emojis appear to be rendered in a monochrome version in your editor. I've experienced a similar problem with the display of emojis in IntelliJ on macOS.

At first, I thought it was due to a character encoding setting. This turned out to be unrelated as my file encoding is set to UTF-8 everywhere.

After living with the problem for quite some time, the solution I've found to have emojis display right for me is to **set the fallback font** (for symbols not supported by the main font) to **"Apple Color Emoji"** for both the editor and the console.

The corresponding UI path for this setting is listed below.

- **Preferences > Editor > Font**

When a color scheme font setting overrides the editor font, then the following paths can apply.

- **Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > Color Scheme Font**
- **Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > Console Font**

"Show only monospaced fonts" will need to be disabled temporarily to show the emoji font under "Fallback font".

Additionally, I made "Paste without Formatting" be my default paste option so that emojis can be pasted directly, without risk of being transformed into Unicode escape sequences.

The result is that emojis display as expected for me throughout the IDE, making a big difference to my coding pleasure!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any alternative equivalent font (like apple color emoji) for windows 10?

Comment: @SundaraRaghavan The **"Noto Color Emoji"** font from Google might help: https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/emoji/.

Comment: yes I got it from Google search. I remember I have tried it long time ago. But still there is no way to do it in Windows 10 intellij idea

Comment: @SundaraRaghavan Are you able to see the "Noto Color Emoji" font in the "Fallback font" field on Windows 10?

Comment: I could select Noto color emoji as a Fallback font as shown in the url link: https://ibb.co/FqDsX6f But I still see it monochrome only. Looks like it is still not supported in windows 10

Comment: @SundaraRaghavan I noticed "Noto Color Emoji" isn't supposed to work on macOS or Windows due to the format. On Windows, can you try **"Segoe UI Emoji"?**

Comment: yes I tried that as well earlier but no luck with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The code editor now correctly handles Unicode emoji characters. On Mac OS X emoji characters are rendered as colored images. On Windows and Linux emoji are rendered as monochrome characters.
Source:   https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/12/intellij-idea-2017-1-eap-is-open/